# COUNTIFS formula with double array criteria and exceptions

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, criteria, countif

I have COUNTIFS formula with double array criteria and multiple exceptions (.-/%#)

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(D2;{"Txt1";"Txt2";"Txt3";"Txt4";"Txt5"}&" Nr."&{1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9}&"*";D2;"<>*.";D2;"<>*-";D2;"<>*/";D2;"<>*%";D2;"<>*#"))=0
```

And i want to optimize/combine all exceptions in one new array. Something like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(D2;{"Txt1";"Txt2";"Txt3";"Txt4";"Txt5"}&" Nr."&{1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9}&"*";D2;"<>*"&{".";"-";"/";"%";"#"}))=0
```

I studdy [this](https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/) explanation, but its too much over me.

P.S.

*My version of excel for arrays use punctuation ; and \*

*Your excel version maybe use another combination like ; and , or , and .*

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the difference between how `OR` and `AND` statements are constructed within `COUNTIFS`.

For a given set of criteria, if you pass the elements of that set as an *array* to `COUNTIFS`, you are effectively performing an `OR` statement.

If, however, you pass each of those elements as a separate *criteria parameter* within `COUNTIFS`, you are effectively performing an `AND` statement.

So the two are not simply interchangeable for the sake of formula brevity.

For example:

`=COUNTIFS(A1,"<>*A",A1,"<>*B",A1,"<>*C")`

and

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1,"*"&{"A";"B";"C"}))`

are very different constructions.

The first is effectively checking whether:

The entry in `A1` does not end with "A"
**AND**
the entry in `A1` does not end with "B"
**AND**
the entry in `A1` does not end with "C"

Whereas the second is effectively checking whether:

The entry in `A1` does not end with "A"
**OR**
the entry in `A1` does not end with "B"
**OR**
the entry in `A1` does not end with "C"

With `A1` containing "XYZ", for example

`=COUNTIFS(A1,"<>*A",A1,"<>*B",A1,"<>*C")`

will return 1, whereas

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(D2,"<>*"&{"A";"B";"C"}))`

will return 3.

There are also two other major issues with your intended abbreviation, which I will just summarize here:

1. `OR` criteria with the `<>` operator do not make logical sense
2. As XOR LX points out in that article you reference, unless you are 'pairing' elements within each set of (similarly dimensioned) array criteria, you cannot hope to create a construction which employs more than 2 sets of array criteria